# ayuda con problema en funcion change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

estoy haciendo un aplicacion de gestion de ligas, una de la paginas es generar el resultado del àrtido, en la que cargo todos los jugadores de cada equipo, con un check para marcar si juega dicho jugador, al activar este check permite poner el numero de goles que ha marcado.

Mi problema, es que tengo un input number, desactivado, en el que quiero que automaticamente se cambie el valor sumando los goles de cada jugador, pero no me lo esta haciendo bien, segun va cambiando el input va sumando, por lo que si un jugador ha marcado 2 goles, pone el ha habido 3 goles (suma el 2 y el 1, al pasar por el 1)

Os adjunto la funcion jquery

```
$(':input[type="number"]').change(function () {
    var totalGoles= 0
    $("#tablaEquipoLocal :input[type='number']").each(function(){
        totalGoles = parseInt($(this).val()) + totalGoles
    }); 
    $("#golesEqLocal").val(totalGoles)
});
```

y esta la parte html del equipo local, habria otra igual del visitante

```
<table id="tablaEquipoLocal">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colsapan="4">EQUIPO LOCAL</th>
                            <th>GOLES LOCAL</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="4">${equipoLocal.nombreEquipo}</th>
                            <th><input type="number" id="golesEqLocal" name="golesEqLocal" disabled="disabled" max="10"
                                    min="0" step="1" value="0" size="2" maxlength="2"  data-check="golesJugLocal_${jugadoresLocalTemp.idJugador}"/>
                            <input type="hidden" id="golesEquipoLocal" name="golesEquipoLocal"  data-check="golesJugLocal_${jugadoresLocalTemp.idJugador}"/></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Dorsal</th>
                            <th>Nombre Jugador</th>
                            <th>Posicion</th>
                            <th>Juega</th>
                            <th>Goles</th>
                        </tr>
                        <c:forEach var="jugadoresLocalTemp" items="${jugadoresLocal}">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="centrado"><input type="hidden" name="idJugador" class="idJugador" value="${jugadoresLocalTemp.idJugador}"/>${jugadoresLocalTemp.dorsal}</td>
                                <td>${jugadoresLocalTemp.getNombreCompleto()}</td>
                                <td>${jugadoresLocalTemp.posicion}</td>
                                <td class="centrado"><input type="checkbox"
                                    name="chkjuegaJugLocal_${jugadoresLocalTemp.idJugador}"
                                    id="chkjuegaJugLocal_${jugadoresLocalTemp.idJugador}" /></td>
                                <td class="alineadoDerecha"><input type="number"
                                    name="golesJugLocal_${jugadoresLocalTemp.idJugador}"
                                    id="golesJugLocal_${jugadoresLocalTemp.idJugador}" data-check="chkjuegaJugLocal_${jugadoresLocalTemp.idJugador}" max="10"
                                    min="0" step="1" value="0" size="2" maxlength="2"
                                    disabled="disabled" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día.

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
$(':input[type="number"]').change(function () {
    var totalGoles= 0
    $("#tablaEquipoLocal tbody :input[type='number']").each(function(){
        totalGoles = parseInt($(this).val()) + totalGoles
    }); 
    $("#golesEqLocal").val(totalGoles)
});
```

Se agrega `tbody`; de esa forma se excluye aplique el `change` al **input** donde reflejas la sumatoria. Esto es lo que percibo esta dando el comportamiento que mencionas.

Recibe saludos cordiales.

Comment: Perfecto, ya funciona bien. Muchas gracias!